# Making new function javascript, with jQuery (doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, new-operator

I have created this function:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function createTooltip(var elementX, var contentX)
    {
        $(elementX).qtip({
            content: contentX,
            style: { name: 'cream' },
        });
    }
</script>
```

after, when i am using this function:

```
createTooltip('#myelement','This is my content text');
```

but this doesn't work (does nothing)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  You don't need to put the `var` in the argument when creating a function.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to declare `var` in the parenthesis, they're expected, because of the context, to be variables. Just remove the `var` keywords and use:

```
function createTooltip(elementX, contentX)
{
    $(elementX).qtip({
        content: contentX,
        style: { name: 'cream' },
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`function createTooltip(var elementX, var contentX)`
is not valid Javascript.

Change to `function createTooltip(elementX, contentX)`

Also, `<script language="javascript">` is deprecated, use `<script type="text/javascript">`